# Can $G^2$ statistic in log-linear model for contingency tables be negative?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, likelihood-ratio, contingency-tables, kullback-leibler, log-linear

Can $G^2$ statistic of log-linear (unsaturated) model in contingency tables be negative? Since saturated model with perfect fit has $G^2=0$ I don't think the unsaturated models can get negative $G^2$. In need of insight, since I might have run into some miscalculations.

Comment: Depending on the order I’ve entered models in some R functions, I’ve run issues like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G-test) that the $G^2$-statistic has the form of (twice) a Kullback-Leibler divergence, see [Why is Kullback Leibler Divergence always positive?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/464509/why-is-kullback-leibler-divergence-always-positive/464528#464528). More precisely 
$$ \DeclareMathOperator{\KL}{KL}
   G^2 = 2\sum_i O_i \log\frac{O_i}{E_i}=2N\KL\left(\frac{O_i}{N}   || \frac{E_i}{N}  \right)
$$ where $N$ is the total count.  It is also related to the deviance in generalized linear models, and is in fact the Deviance (in R terminology, Null deviance - Residual deviance) in a logistic regression model for the contingency table.